# Tool to view a web page's div structure

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, inspect

Is there a tool out there that can show you an entire page's div layout structure?

I'm using Chrome's inspect tool and it shows individual divs as you scroll through, but I'm hoping there's a tool out there that will look at the entire page's structure to help with div layout "debugging."

I've googled in general and on here and haven't found anything.

Thanks.

Comment: Asking for such things is not allowed on SO and this question will soon be closed. "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam." -- http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Open up the web tools and create a new CSS rule:

```
div { outline: 1px solid red !important; }
```

[image: it looks something like this]

If you are tired of adding the rule after every refresh, add this code as target to a bookmark (or drag'n'drop it into your bookmarks panel):

```
javascript:{s=document.createElement("style");s.appendChild(document.createTextNode("div {outline: 1px solid red}"));document.head.appendChild(s);void(0)}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's this thing called [Div Checker](http://www.tormus.com/tools/div_checker)
This will basicly check if there are any div tags not closing correctly. But also gives you a map of your structure. So this might do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [SnappySnippet](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/snappysnippet/mdmgnnmlhdfofojkdoajglgmhaicejkk?hl=en-US) extension in Google Chrome

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/snappysnippet/mdmgnnmlhdfofojkdoajglgmhaicejkk?hl=en-US

Comment: just search for snappysnippet chrome